# The container name is already in use by container -- gitlab ci

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am getting the following error during the "test_image" step when running tests against docker images in my gitlab CI pipeline. I cannot reproduce it locally, it only occurs on the gitlab runner box. Any ideas?

> The container name "/common_run_1" is already in use by container

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN myregistry.gitlab

build_image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker-compose up -d --build
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

pylint:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker-compose run common pylint common

test_image:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker-compose run common nosetests common

push_master_image:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_MASTER_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_MASTER_IMAGE
  only:
    - master

push_prod_image:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_PROD_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_PROD_IMAGE
  only:
    - prod
```

Update:
There are multiple suggestions to simply use "docker-compose down" or "docker stop". I have done this on my gitlab-runner box (completely cleaned out docker processes, images, volumes, and networks), and re-submitted the pipeline request. In this case, I get the same error in the gitlab pipeline. It makes me think there is a concurrency issue in the "test" stage. Furthermore, if I add a "test2" stage and place the "pylint" script inside of it, the pipeline will succeed, further re-enforcing the idea of a concurrency problem.

Comment: I have updated my  answer! Please check!

Answer (score 2):

Your stage:test is having two docker-compose run and both are running using same container name. You can change this by adding `--name test1` in `docker-compose run` of first test  and `--name test2` in `docker-compose run` of second test.

**Original Answer**

Run `docker ps -a` and it will list which container names are already being used. This is caused mostly because you have already run the container using `docker-compose up` and the containers are still up.

Your options are

1. Run `docker-compose down`. This should bring down the already running containers. And should most probably solve your error.
2. If option 1 fails, then you can see which containers are running and stop those containers by running `docker stop <container_name>`.

Comment: The container name should include the `$CI_JOB_ID` variable so it will not clash with pipes running for other commits.

Comment: It's also a good idea to run `docker-compose down` at the end of the script.